# How can I get a SQL query result in CSV format?

Tags: sql, csv, t-sql

I have an SQL query that returns some rows. How can I change it so that the output of the query is in CSV format?

I have found a way to make the result in XML format, but because of the nature of XML the result is too large to be useful.

The query is very large (and it's not really important), so I wont post it here. Here is a link to it.[Link](https://pastebin.com/pHk0NKKc)

```
I don't want the SQL query to save the result as a CSV file.
```

Comment: I misread that, and apologize.

Comment: Question, is this a one time query or will you need to run this multiple times?

Comment: Multiple times, programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
select field1
, '","'
, field2
, '","'
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

YES

try this

```
DECLARE  @query nvarchar(max)

select @query = STUFF(  (SELECT N',' + cast( id as nvarchar)  
from TableX 
--some WHERE clause here as well

FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'')

select  @query
```

NO variable :

```
 select   STUFF(  (SELECT N',' + cast( id as nvarchar)  
 from TableX 
 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'')
```

Comment: This is not a complete solution. You only have this set up to work for id field. If you look at the link provided @user3465882 has some fields that could have commas and double quotes. Also, you don't include the headers for the columns. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values for some standard rules.